# Deserialize nested item by combining UnixDateTimeConverter and ContractResolver

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Given the following JSON, i want to deserialize with Newtonsoft.Json:

```
{
  "ticker": "AAPL",
  "status": "OK",
  "adjusted": true,
  "queryCount": 55,
  "resultsCount": 2,
  "results": [
    {
      "T": "AAPL",
      "v": 31315282,
      "o": 102.87,
      "c": 103.74,
      "h": 103.82,
      "l": 102.65,
      "t": 1549314000000,
      "n": 4
    },
    {
      "T": "AAPL",
      "v": 11315282,
      "o": 102.13,
      "c": 103.44,
      "h": 104.12,
      "l": 102.33,
      "t": 1549315000000,
      "n": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created the class which will deserialize OK:

```
public class Response
{
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool Adjusted { get; set; }
    public int QueryCount { get; set; }     
    public int ResultsCount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public List<OpenHighLowClose> OpenHighLowCloseList { get; set; }
}
```

And i have the following DTO which is used throughout my code (but i don't want to put attributes on this class):

```
public class OpenHighLowClose
{
    public OpenHighLowClose(DateTime dateTime, decimal open, decimal high, decimal low, decimal close, decimal volume)
    {
        DateTime = dateTime;
        Open = open;
        High = high;
        Low = low;
        Close = close;
        Volume = volume;
    }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; private set; }
    public Decimal Open { get; private set; }
    public Decimal High { get; private set; }
    public Decimal Low { get; private set; }
    public Decimal Close { get; private set; }
    public Decimal Volume { get; private set; }
}
```

I need to map via the constructor (which i believe the deserializer will do by default), so for OpenHighLowClose I can write as below:

```
public class OpenHighLowCloseContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> PropertyMappings { get; set; }

    public CustomContractResolver()
    {
        this.PropertyMappings = new Dictionary<string, string> 
        {
            {"t", "DateTime"},
            {"o", "Open"},
            {"h", "High"},
            {"l", "Low"},
            {"c", "Close"},
            {"v", "Volume"},
        };
    }

    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        string resolvedName = null;
        var resolved = this.PropertyMappings.TryGetValue(propertyName, out resolvedName);
        return (resolved) ? resolvedName : base.ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
    }
}
```

How would I go combining the above code so that I can deserialize `Response` using the constructor and timestamp conversion.

I have seen `JsonConverter`, `JsonConstructor`, `CustomContractResolver` and `[JsonConverter(typeof(UnixDateTimeConverter))]` to sort the time conversion out, but i am getting confused how to combine all these classes.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just have an `OpenHighLowCloseDto` (with JSON attributes) for the deserialization, and an adapter to `OpenHighLowClose` once the data is in the DTO objects?  You could then deserialize everything without custom resolvers or constructor concerns.

Comment: I am very tempted to be honest , but I am using the same dto to be used in another library (grpc) to forward the data on to client. Given the data size I need to avoid dto mapping

Comment: @sellotape got this working via `JsonConverter` and posted answer - seems simple enough but best practice compliant... not so sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using `JsonConverter`.

This wasn't so bad in the end, interested on comments if best practice or not:

```
public class AggregateResponse
{
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool Adjusted { get; set; }
    public int QueryCount { get; set; }
    public int ResultsCount { get; set; }
    public List<OpenHighLowClose> Results { get; set; }
}

public class OpenHighLowCloseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        var timestamp = DateTimeOffset
                            .FromUnixTimeMilliseconds((long)obj["t"])
                            .UtcDateTime;

        return new OpenHighLowClose(
                            timestamp,
                            (decimal)obj["o"],
                            (decimal)obj["h"],
                            (decimal)obj["l"],
                            (decimal)obj["c"],
                            (int)obj["v"]);                            
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
                                  => objectType == typeof(OpenHighLowClose);

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
                                  => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And I deserialize with the below:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new OpenHighLowCloseConverter() }
};

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AggregateResponse>(result, settings);
```